# Polling vs subscriptions in Apollo Client?

Tags: apollo-client

Im making a social website. When any user updates or creates new content on the site I need any other users viewing the site to see the change update.

I have comments which requite low latency so a subscription is recommended for this.

I also have events but these don't need such a low latency. Updating every 10 seconds would be fine. Should I also user subscriptions for this or would polling be less expensive for the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subscription has been expressly made for this, it is the best option because the server only updates the response when necessary. However, if you use the other option, you will continuously try to refresh the data and you will be wasting resources from your server. I hope I've helped.

Read more about this here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/#when-to-use-subscriptions

Comment: From that link: "In most cases, intermittent polling or manual refetching are actually the best way to keep your client up to date"

Comment: Yes but if you want low latency on updates...  really if you do not need low latency you can use polling, but I think that for your case like a social network where the content is interactive so that users are really excited about the experience, you need low latency, it's my opinion

Comment: I dont think updating every 10 seconds is "low" latency.

Comment: yes but I also imagine that your store will be so big if it is a social network: "The initial state is large, but the incremental change sets are small. The starting state can be fetched with a query and subsequently updated through a subscription".